# Ubuntu 18.04. VT1000 docking station connected but monitors not working?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, docking

I have a Dell XPS laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 connected to a VisionTek VT1000 universal USB Dock. My setup was working with two monitors, but then my laptop froze while connecting, and after I rebooted it, the monitors no longer seem to work.

I can tell the dock is connected because the mouse connected via the dock is functioning. When I turn each monitor on, one says "No VGA signal from your device" and the other says "No HDMI signal from your device."

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!